# Remove Default gnome session from Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-gnome, gdm

I am not a fan of gnome and just felt that I don't need it in my Ubuntu 18.04 installation. What is the correct way to uninstall it from my system. I have ran the command `sudo apt remove ubuntu-desktop` and `sudo apt autoremove`, but there is still entry of "ubuntu" in gdm login manager.

Please tell me if I am missing something or it is just the entry in gdm and nothing else. If that is the case, then how to remove that entry.

Another thing that when I log into that session, I get a desktop without a panel but there is a top bar.

Comment: Have you find a way?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt remove ubuntu-session
```

will remove the GNOME session.

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

will then remove the packages which are no longer needed.
Please note that you need some other session installed, or you will have no graphical desktop at all. If you upgraded from an older ubuntu version, you likely have the Unity desktop installed. If not,

```
sudo apt install unity-session
```

will do that.